# Using libgc with GNAT?

Tags: garbage-collection, ada, gnat, libgc

I've heard several mentions that Ada supports garbage collection --- and looking at the language design, it's obviously been designed with that in mind.

I have a non-real-time application for which garbage collection would be really, really useful. However I haven't seen any mention of there being a garbage collector available for my compiler, GNAT. This surprises me; even C supports garbage collection, by simply linking against libgc.

If I simply add libgc to my linker line, will it work or will horrible things happen?

Comment: Incidentally, while it doesn't answer my question, if anyone can point me at a decent (i.e. not too cumbersome) Ada equivalent to C++'s `shared_ptr`, I would gladly use that instead of libgc.

Comment: You could always try to run ACATS with libgc, and see if it reports any errors.

Comment: `shared_ptr`: try AdaCore Gems [97](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-97-reference-counting-in-ada-part-1/), [99](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-99-reference-counting-in-ada-part-2-task-safety/), [100](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-100-reference-counting-in-ada-part-3-weak-references/), [107](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-107-preventing-deallocation-for-reference-counted-types/), [123](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-123-implicit-dereferencing-in-ada-2012/).

Comment: Also [GNATColl.Refcount](http://docs.adacore.com/gnatcoll-docs/refcount.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a libgc binding as part of the AdaCL library here: http://adacl.sourceforge.net/

However, the libgc documentation also says that libgc can't see pointers stored in blocks allocated via system `malloc()`. This means that an access which is only stored in an object allocated from the default memory pool won't be considered a root and may be invalidated at any point. This disqualifies the use of standard Ada containers from storing accesses to collectable objects! This might *also* apply to the secondary stack --- but I don't know what the secondary stack is used for.

However, my investigations do show that garbage collection does naively work:

```
while true loop
  p := new big_thing_t;
end loop;
```

...runs forever. So it's probably theoretical possible to do, but right now I don't think it's safe.

Comment: The secondary stack is used for unconstrained objects - objects with parameters unknown at compile-time. For instance a string initialized with a function call, or a matrix m x n. This removes much of the need for garbage collection - and for pointers at all.

Answer (score 1):

> However I haven't seen any mention of there being a garbage collector
>   available for my compiler, GNAT. This surprises me; even C supports
>   garbage collection, by simply linking against libgc.

You could use GNAT targeting the JVM.

I *think* that the reason simply linking against `libgc` won't give you garbage collection [at least to my knowledge] is because GNAT doesn't have any notion of how to use it. However, given that GNAT uses the GCC backend I don't see why it shouldn't "just work" if it does w/ C.